"WebDriverException: The requested resource could not be found while using AppiumLibrary in Robot Framework"
I'm encountering an issue while using the AppiumLibrary in Robot Framework. When trying to open an application using the Open Application keyword, I'm getting a WebDriverException with the message "The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource." Below is the relevant portion of the test log:[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/0MBBd.png)
I'm using AppiumLibrary for Robot Framework to automate testing on Android devices. I've verified that the Appium server is running and that the desired capabilities are correctly configured in my test script.
here is my test script:
enter image description here
Could anyone provide insights into why this error might be occurring and how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
